# AttributeError: '_shims' object has no attribute 'InstallRequirement'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, amazon-ec2

I'm sorry if I didn't speak well in English because I'm not good at English.
Specifically, the environment was being constructed with reference to [this article](https://qiita.com/pokotsun/items/1272479e36c5146c6609#9-db%E3%82%92postgresql%E3%81%AB%E5%A4%89%E6%9B%B4).
The error occurred when 「pipenv install gunicorn」 command was executed to introduce “gunicorn”.
The execution result of 「pipenv install gunicorn」 is as follows.

```
/home/app-user/.local/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/attr/_make.py:618: RuntimeWarning: Missing ctypes.  Some features like bare super() or accessing __class__ will not work with slots classes.
  set_closure_cell(cell, cls)
Installing gunicorn…
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/app-user/.local/python/bin/pipenv", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/home/app-user/.local/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 764, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/app-user/.local/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 717, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/app-user/.local/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1137, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/app-user/.local/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 956, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/app-user/.local/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 555, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/app-user/.local/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/decorators.py", line 64, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/app-user/.local/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 555, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/app-user/.local/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/decorators.py", line 17, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/app-user/.local/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/cli/command.py", line 254, in install
    editable_packages=state.installstate.editables,
  File "/home/app-user/.local/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 1909, in do_install
    pkg_requirement = Requirement.from_line(pkg_line)
  File "/home/app-user/.local/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/requirementslib/models/requirements.py", line 1068, in from_line
    if isinstance(line, pip_shims.shims.InstallRequirement):
  File "/home/app-user/.local/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/pip_shims/shims.py", line 254, in __getattr__
    return super(_shims, self).__getattribute__(*args, **kwargs)
AttributeError: '_shims' object has no attribute 'InstallRequirement'
```

We would appreciate your help in resolving the above error.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) for python version management you can follow the following steps:

1. Make sure that you have correctly setup pyenv and you have following lines in either bashrc, bash_profile or zshrc; depending upon your operating system and shell. For more information check [documentation](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv)

   ```
   export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
   export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
   eval "$(pyenv init -)"
   ```
2. Remove the old python installation using `pyenv unistall X.X.X` where `X.X.X` is the version number of python.
3. Reinstall the python using `pyenv install X.X.X`